# Google Adsense ad showed up then disappeared

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I've gotten google ads to work before on another website of mine but it was a major pain to do. Currently I'm trying to get ads on a new site setup but it won't show the ad. I got it to show once then it went away.I have the code copied and pasted exactly as google told me to do but it's not showing up. Is there something else I have to do so I can view the ad and position it on my site? Thanks.

Comment: You're gonna have to be more descriptive with the steps you've taken and any errors you're seeing. "My thing isn't working, help?" type questions are hard to answer.

Comment: most good browsers have "developer tools" which includes amongst other things a console, element inspector, debugger - as a developer, you could use those tools when developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the site on an actual domain and verifying it with Google Webmaster tools. Once I had it on a live domain and was verified I was able to just copy and paste the code that google supplied to me and it worked without any issues.